# How to better store the filters from the client side in the Session

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, filter

Nearly every page of our application has several filters on it. My current goal is to implement a mechanism to store the filters and preselect them when a user re-opens a page, so at least during one session user don't have select them over and over again when he's opening a page, or moving from page to page.

The application is written with ASP.NEt MVC and we use a lot of javascript to handle filtering. At the moment a lot of filtering is done only on the client side(for example, the complete data for the grid is retrieved and all further filtering is made only on the client).

I was thinking of these steps:

- Base class for the controllers: Method1 takes data send by the method from the common.js and saves it in the Session.
- common JS: to common.js add a method, which accepts a selection made by a user, and together with the name of the control and name of the page sends it to the server Method1 in order to store new selection in the Session object.
- Base class for the controllers: Method2 accepts name of the controller, name of the page and retrieves Session object.
- JS of individual pages: in the onload event specifying all existing filters and getting data from the Method2.

However, I'm not sure that this solution is universal and optimal.

And I don't want to reinvent the wheel. Is there any already existing solutions or patterns for this task? Or any ideas how this can be done better?

Answer (score 0):

One of the way that comes to my mind is using of Cookies rather than the session as it just the section and you can read the cookies from the JavaScript itself. it will save the server resource as you will not save anything in the Session. If your selection criteria is not very sensitive , there should not be any security issue

Comment: Thanks for the idea! It sounds reasonable, but I think we will stick to the Session as we want to store selection data in the database later, so user can use his filters, when he opens website on another machine.